# Is it possible using Regular Expression in Oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have a name in table like `chandreshkumar nareshbhai`. I want to update it to `chandresh naresh`

Is it possible using Regular Expression in Oracle?

Comment: What is the general pattern ?

Comment: devide by space and if last character of each words like 'kumar' or bhai then replace it with blank.

Comment: It's posssible without regular expression: `update TABLE set name ='chandresh naresh' where name = 'chandreshkumar nareshbhai'`

Comment: I have table table that contain words like 'kumar', 'bhai'.I have to do same for each words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
update YOUR_TABLE  
set COL = regexp_replace(regexp_replace(COL, 'kumar$|bhai$', ''), 'kumar\s|bhai\s', ' ')
```